# Compare dates based on group in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

Alright, so I want to get the difference between date and times based on the user that logged them. I can't seem to find anything online about this so this is my last resort. I have this:

```
timePage['Time spent on page'] = timePage['date'].diff()
```

It gives me the difference between the dates on my date column, but it also doesn't take into account the different users. I've grouped my data by user, then instance then date and want the code to reach the bottom of the user group and say that the next date shouldn't be compared to this date as it's a different user. 
Also, it doesn't work for the first index of my data. so how would I get it to compare the first and second index and then store that on the first indexed row?

Sample Data:

```
L = [{ "user" : "43tuhgn34",
   "Instance" : "f34yh",
   "Date" : "2019-02-14 12:54:52.000000+00:00"},
 { "user" : "43tuhgn34",
   "Instance" : "wrg32",
   "Date" : "2019-02-15 11:34:12.000000+00:00"},
{ "user" : "erg34g",
   "Instance" : "f34yh",
   "Date" : "2018-03-11 17:21:26.430000+00:00"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with lambda function, `bfill` here working per groups:

```
timePage = pd.DataFrame(L)

timePage['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(timePage['Date'])

timePage['Time spent on page'] = (timePage.groupby('user')['Date']
                                          .apply(lambda x: x.diff().bfill()))
print (timePage)
        user Instance                             Date Time spent on page
0  43tuhgn34    f34yh        2019-02-14 12:54:52+00:00           22:39:20
1  43tuhgn34    wrg32        2019-02-15 11:34:12+00:00           22:39:20
2     erg34g    f34yh 2018-03-11 17:21:26.430000+00:00                NaT
```

If all groups has at least 2 rows is possible chain [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with `bfill`, but be carefull, because `bfill` here NOT working per groups:

```
timePage = pd.DataFrame(L)

timePage['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(timePage['Date'])

timePage['Time spent on page'] = timePage.groupby('user')['Date'].diff().bfill()
print (timePage)
```

Comment: Thank you, but slight issue is that the index is out. The third result is the difference between the second and third date, but I need it to be the difference between the third and fourth date if that makes sense

Comment: @AgentArachnid - There are no `3rd` and `4th` datetimes in sample data, so not possible. Is possible create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: It was just a sample. Is there a way to move the entire column up one row? The times are accurate, but just need to moved up a row

Comment: I found the shift function so I'll just use that. @jezrael Thanks for the code, it works beautifully,

Comment: @AgentArachnid - Do you think `.apply(lambda x: x.diff().bfill().shift(-1))` ?

Comment: That worked as well. Thank you so much. I misplaced the shift function outside the apply function